# Broken attachment encryption with python and GnuPG

Tags: python, email-attachments, gnupg

I've taken all the forks of gpg-mailgate and put all the working parts together to get it almost totally working.  The last issue I"m having is that attachments come through encrpted as filename.originalextension.pgp BUT are undecryptable.

Here is the full code of the mailgate plugin as I have it working.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from ConfigParser import RawConfigParser
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
import email
import email.message
import re
import GnuPG
import smtplib
import sys

# Read configuration from /etc/gpg-mailgate.conf
_cfg = RawConfigParser()
_cfg.read('/etc/gpg-mailgate.conf')
cfg = dict()
for sect in _cfg.sections():
        cfg[sect] = dict()
        for (name, value) in _cfg.items(sect):
                cfg[sect][name] = value

# Read e-mail from stdin
raw = sys.stdin.read()
raw_message = email.message_from_string( raw )
from_addr = raw_message['From']
to_addrs = sys.argv[1:]

def send_msg( message, recipients = None ):
        if recipients == None:
                recipients = to_addrs
        if cfg.has_key('logging') and cfg['logging'].has_key('file'):
                log = open(cfg['logging']['file'], 'a')
                log.write("Sending email to: <%s>\n" % '> <'.join( recipients ))
                log.close()
        relay = (cfg['relay']['host'], int(cfg['relay']['port']))
        smtp = smtplib.SMTP(relay[0], relay[1])
        smtp.sendmail( from_addr, recipients, message.as_string() )

def encrypt_payload( payload, gpg_to_cmdline ):
        gpg = GnuPG.GPGEncryptor( cfg['gpg']['keyhome'], gpg_to_cmdline )
        raw_payload = payload.get_payload(decode=True)
        gpg.update( raw_payload )
        if "-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----" in raw_payload and "-----END PGP MESSAGE-----" in raw_payload:
          return payload
        payload.set_payload( gpg.encrypt() )
        if payload['Content-Disposition']:
                payload.replace_header( 'Content-Disposition', re.sub(r'filename="([^"]+)"', r'filename="\1.pgp"', payload['Content-Disposition']) )
        if payload['Content-Type']:
                payload.replace_header( 'Content-Type', re.sub(r'name="([^"]+)"', r'name="\1.pgp"', payload['Content-Type']) )
#               if payload.get_content_type() != 'text/plain' and payload.get_content_type != 'text/html':
                if 'name="' in payload['Content-Type']:
                        payload.replace_header( 'Content-Type', re.sub(r'^[a-z/]+;', r'application/octet-stream;', payload['Content-Type']) )
                        payload.set_payload( "\n".join( filter( lambda x:re.search(r'^(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})*(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}==|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{3}=|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})$',x), payload.get_payload().split("\n") ) ) )
        return payload

def encrypt_all_payloads( payloads, gpg_to_cmdline ):
        encrypted_payloads = list()
        if type( payloads ) == str:
                msg = email.message.Message()
                msg.set_payload( payloads )
                return encrypt_payload( msg, gpg_to_cmdline ).as_string()
        for payload in payloads:
                if( type( payload.get_payload() ) == list ):
                        encrypted_payloads.append( encrypt_all_payloads( payload.get_payload(), gpg_to_cmdline ) )
                else:
                        encrypted_payloads.append( [encrypt_payload( payload, gpg_to_cmdline )] )
        return sum(encrypted_payloads, [])

def get_msg( message ):
        if not message.is_multipart():
                return message.get_payload()
        return '\n\n'.join( [str(m) for m in message.get_payload()] )

keys = GnuPG.public_keys( cfg['gpg']['keyhome'] )
gpg_to = list()
ungpg_to = list()

for to in to_addrs:
        domain = to.split('@')[1]
        if domain in cfg['default']['domains'].split(','):
                if to in keys:
                        gpg_to.append( (to, to) )
                elif cfg.has_key('keymap') and cfg['keymap'].has_key(to):
                        gpg_to.append( (to, cfg['keymap'][to]) )
        else:
                ungpg_to.append(to)

if gpg_to == list():
        if cfg['default'].has_key('add_header') and cfg['default']['add_header'] == 'yes':
                raw_message['X-GPG-Mailgate'] = 'Not encrypted, public key not found'
        send_msg( raw_message )
        exit()

if ungpg_to != list():
        send_msg( raw_message, ungpg_to )

if cfg.has_key('logging') and cfg['logging'].has_key('file'):
        log = open(cfg['logging']['file'], 'a')
        log.write("Encrypting email to: %s\n" % ' '.join( map(lambda x: x[0], gpg_to) ))
        log.close()

if cfg['default'].has_key('add_header') and cfg['default']['add_header'] == 'yes':
        raw_message['X-GPG-Mailgate'] = 'Encrypted by GPG Mailgate'

gpg_to_cmdline = list()
gpg_to_smtp = list()
for rcpt in gpg_to:
        gpg_to_smtp.append(rcpt[0])
        gpg_to_cmdline.extend(rcpt[1].split(','))

encrypted_payloads = encrypt_all_payloads( raw_message.get_payload(), gpg_to_cmdline )
raw_message.set_payload( encrypted_payloads )

send_msg( raw_message, gpg_to_smtp )
```

My client ( both roundcube and k-9 ), do not know what to do with the file. 
From command line if I do a gpg --decrypt filename.txt.pgp I get:
    gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
    gpg: decrypt_message failed: eof

Headers of email are:

```
User-Agent: K-9 Mail for Android
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="----YR49011GO0MWM753ETYWUA7CBOKGAV"
Subject: New with attachments 
From: Bruce Markey <bruce@secryption.com>
Date: Fri, 13 Sep 2013 06:18:03 -0400
To: "bruce@packetaddiction.com" <bruce@packetaddiction.com>
Message-ID: <53178821-6d6c-4b7d-b9c7-5a49034da1ef@email.android.com>
X-GPG-Mailgate: Encrypted by GPG Mailgate
```

I'm not even sure "what" to debug since everything looks ok, and there is a total lack of errors.

If anyone has any direction I'd appreciate it.

Update:
I came across this [Decrypt gpg file attached from email (file.pgp)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12900542/decrypt-gpg-file-attached-from-email-file-pgp)

I decided to add a line to write raw to a log file.

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
X-Received: by 10.68.130.1 with SMTP id oa1mr18868651pbb.35.1379162867744;
Sat, 14 Sep 2013 05:47:47 -0700 (PDT)
Received: by 10.68.46.72 with HTTP; Sat, 14 Sep 2013 05:47:47 -0700 (PDT)
Date: Sat, 14 Sep 2013 08:47:47 -0400
Message-ID: <CACRtyey-L9Z5JGNG4bheYqJ7tVK+6qfigmanH9pTUk0ute5gEw@mail.gmail.com>
Subject: Test with attachment - Saturday
From: Bruce Markey <bmarkey@gmail.com>
To: bruce@packetaddiction.com
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=047d7b10ca15d1c7b904e65760eb

--047d7b10ca15d1c7b904e65760eb
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1

Just a simple test with txt attachment

--047d7b10ca15d1c7b904e65760eb
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=US-ASCII; name="TestAttach.txt"
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="TestAttach.txt"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
X-Attachment-Id: f_hlkty4930

VGhpcyBpcyBqdXN0IGEgdGVzdCBvZiB0aGUgYXR0YWNobWVudHMuIApUaGlzIGlzIGEgc2ltcGxl
IHRleHQgZmlsZS4gCgo=
--047d7b10ca15d1c7b904e65760eb--
```

Since this is being written raw it's pre encryption. So should I be decoding the base64 prior to encryption?

After staring at this for awhile I don't understand why this line is here.

```
if 'name="' in payload['Content-Type']:
payload.replace_header( 'Content-Type', re.sub(r'^[a-z/]+;', r'application/octet-  stream;', payload['Content-Type']) )
payload.set_payload( "\n".join( filter( lambda x:re.search(r'^(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})*(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}==|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{3}=|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})$',x), payload.get_payload().split("\n") ) ) )
```

Why change to application/octet-stream?

UPDATE:

I think I got it working unless I'm doing something horribly wrong.  I changed the following:

```
def get_msg( message ):
    if not message.is_multipart():
        return message.get_payload()
return '\n\n'.join( [base64.decodestring(str(m)) for m in message.get_payload()] )
```

This now allows me to actually run gpg --decrypt filename.txt .

( I assume that most attachments will come through as base64 although I'll probably add a test for all content-transfer-encoding types. )

Answer (score 0):

The attachment needed to be decoded, content-transfer-encoding, prior to encrypting.  See code in update of original question.